# git pull terminal allow everyone

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

We have a staging server and at the moment, when I go to the server in the terminal and perform a `git pull`, everything works fine. When my colleague tries it, he's asked for my password. How can I change this so that everyone is able to perform a pull on that server and not just me?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ssh.

create your very own keypair [like this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#generating-a-new-ssh-key) 
then add the public key to your bitbucket account
replace your remote link with the respective ssh one
using `git pull` will now no longer ask for a password

Answer (score 0):

try this code by write it in terminal

```html
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```